# Protecting formal shoes from scuffs

Tags: clothes

I'm a utility cyclist. Usually when I ride, I wear good outdoor shoes that are waterproof and hard-wearing, so it's OK if they get scuffed on pedals or splashed with mud or oil from the road surface. (Proper mudguards help a lot but still aren't 100% effective.)

On occasion, I go to an event in formal dress, which entails wearing black, polished leather shoes. It's a lot harder to keep these clean and shiny. If I've a long ride to get there, I'll usually wear some shoes that are better for cycling and keep my black pair in my bag. But if I'm only riding 10 minutes to get to an event in town, having to pack a second pair and change them is a lot less convenient.

Is there an easier alternative? A plastic bag over the shoes, secured with elastic, would keep them clean, but not (I fear) protect them from scuffs; besides, I'd be afraid of slipping when I put my foot down. Any other ideas?

Comment: I feel your pain. I've tried doing that for a long time. My conclusion was: If you need to look smart - don't cycle or change clothes/shoes on the venue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of rubber overshoes that would work. Two of the most common brands are Totes and Tingley. Try a search for "rubber overshoes" on Google or [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_12?url=search-alias=apparel&field-keywords=rubber%20overshoes&sprefix=rubber%20overs,apparel,224).

These will protect your shoes, provide some traction, and can be rolled up and strapped to the frame or seat with velcro.

Below is an example of the Totes brand:

[image: Totes Overshoes]